# Отключить автоматический вход в систему

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня есть система: Ubuntu Mate 15.10, которая выполняет автоматический вход в систему в консольном режиме, что делает не возможным использование консоли для других пользователей. А также хочу поменять имя данного пользователя. Для этого из под другого пользователя выполняю команда

```
usermod -l newname oldname
```

говорит

```
usermod: user user is currently used by process 860
```

Завершаю все процессы данного пользователя

```
pkill -u 1000
```

но после команда who сного показывает его.
Видимо сного автологинится. Как это отключить?

Вывод команды ps faux

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [migration/
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [migration/
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [migration/
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [migration/
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [khelper]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [kdevtmpfs]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [netns]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [perf]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [khungtaskd
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [writeback]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [crypto]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [bioset]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [kblockd]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [rpciod]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [kswapd0]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [fsnotify_m
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [nfsiod]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [kthrotld]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [VCHIQ-0]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [VCHIQr-0]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [VCHIQs-0]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [iscsi_eh]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [dwc_otg]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [DWC Notifi
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/u8
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [VCHIQka-0]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [SMIO]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [deferwq]
root        53  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:02  \_ [mmcqd/0]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [jbd2/mmcbl
root        56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [ext4-rsv-c
root        58  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:
root        59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [ipv6_addrc
root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:
root       106  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:
root       197  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [cfg80211]
root       199  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [brcmf_wq/m
root       200  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [brcmf_wdog
root       212  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [ksdioirqd/
root       248  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:
root       403  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:
root       472  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:11   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:
root      1290  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:12   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:
root      1495  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:16   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:
root      9002  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:17   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:
root      9090  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:24   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:
root      9107  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:28   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:
root      9128  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:32   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:
root      9145  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:33   0:00  \_ [kworker/u8
root      9556  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:38   0:00  \_ [kworker/u8
root      9560  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:40   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:
root      9597  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:40   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:
root      9611  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:40   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:
root      9696  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:41   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:
root         1  0.2  0.3   5468  3636 ?        Ss   11:11   0:03 /sbin/init spla
root       127  0.0  0.3   9700  3032 ?        Ss   11:11   0:01 /lib/systemd/sy
root       136  0.0  0.3  12060  2916 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
root       347  0.0  0.1   1752  1208 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/avahi
whoopsie   349  0.0  0.9  55276  8904 ?        Ssl  11:11   0:00 /usr/bin/whoops
root       354  0.0  0.5  37808  5260 ?        Ssl  11:11   0:00 /usr/lib/accoun
root       356  0.0  0.6  39792  6460 ?        Ssl  11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/Modem
root       363  0.0  0.2   5008  2108 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron 
avahi      365  0.0  0.2   4564  2284 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 avahi-daemon: r
avahi      394  0.0  0.0   4428   296 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ avahi-daemo
root       366  0.0  0.2   3424  2176 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
syslog     367  0.0  0.2  31240  2080 ?        Ssl  11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsysl
root       376  0.0  1.1  82528 10772 ?        Ssl  11:11   0:01 /usr/sbin/Netwo
root       459  0.0  0.7   7760  6780 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ /sbin/dhcli
nobody     478  0.0  0.3   7312  2928 ?        S    11:11   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/d
message+   382  0.1  0.3   5820  3484 ?        Ss   11:11   0:02 /usr/bin/dbus-d
root       386  0.0  0.0   1456    88 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/rngd 
root       395  0.0  0.3   4964  3276 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/irqba
root       411  0.0  0.4   8348  4188 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd 
root       416  0.0  0.6  33264  5908 ?        Ssl  11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/cups-
root       418  0.0  0.6  38144  6276 ?        Ssl  11:11   0:01 /usr/lib/policy
root       424  0.0  0.4  43876  4520 ?        Ssl  11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/light
root       435  0.9  4.4 115404 42244 tty7     Rsl+ 11:11   0:17  \_ /usr/bin/X 
root       906  0.0  0.5  28384  5036 ?        Sl   11:11   0:00  \_ lightdm --s
nor        949  0.0  1.2  49832 12076 ?        Ssl  11:12   0:00      \_ mate-se
nor        999  0.0  0.0   3016   212 ?        Ss   11:12   0:00          \_ /us
nor       1023  0.0  1.8 206004 17748 ?        Sl   11:12   0:01          \_ /us
nor       1027  0.0  1.8 130824 17652 ?        Sl   11:12   0:01          \_ mar
nor       1033  0.2  2.4 182996 23604 ?        Sl   11:12   0:03          \_ mat
nor       1057  0.2  3.5 185808 33964 ?        Sl   11:12   0:04          \_ caj
nor       1074  0.0  1.2  39732 11388 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00          \_ /us
nor       1084  0.0  1.2  49636 11776 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00          \_ mat
nor       1092  0.1  2.0  38232 18968 ?        Sl   11:12   0:02          \_ /us
nor       1093  0.0  2.1  68336 20212 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00          \_ upd
nor       1097  0.0  1.4  51376 13732 ?        Sl   11:12   0:01          \_ mat
nor       1102  0.0  1.3  50396 12740 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00          \_ mat
nor       1103  0.0  2.1 142596 19912 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00          \_ mat
nor       1104  0.0  0.5  56504  5256 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00          \_ /us
nor       1120  0.0  2.6 110228 24768 ?        Sl   11:12   0:01          \_ nm-
root       440  0.0  0.4   7040  4612 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /sbin/wpa_suppl
kernoops   605  0.0  0.1   6632  1740 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/kerne
ntp        622  0.0  0.3   4912  3128 ?        Ss   11:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd 
nor        935  0.0  0.3   5316  3424 ?        Ss   11:12   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
nor        940  0.0  0.1   8456  1324 ?        S    11:12   0:00  \_ (sd-pam)   
nor        945  0.0  0.5  46432  5224 ?        SLl  11:12   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-
nor       1002  0.0  0.1   4996  1304 ?        S    11:12   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-l
nor       1003  0.0  0.2   5312  2632 ?        Ss   11:12   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-d
nor       1016  0.0  0.3  23564  3452 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/
nor       1032  0.0  0.4  36100  4276 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
nor       1038  0.0  0.3  52108  3304 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
nor       1053  0.0  0.7 155980  7412 ?        S<l  11:12   0:00 /usr/bin/pulsea
rtkit     1054  0.0  0.2  22300  1980 ?        SNsl 11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/
nor       1060  0.0  2.0  93084 19492 ?        Sl   11:12   0:01 /usr/lib/mate-p
nor       1062  0.0  1.7  80768 16472 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/mate-a
nor       1068  0.0  0.5  37648  5200 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
nor       1071  0.0  2.0  49556 19260 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 tilda
nor       1195  0.0  0.1   1936  1248 ?        S    11:12   0:00  \_ gnome-pty-h
nor       1196  0.0  0.4   6360  3976 pts/0    Ss+  11:12   0:00  \_ /bin/bash
root      1078  0.0  0.6  54052  6024 ?        Ssl  11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/udisks
nor       1140  0.0  0.4  35128  3864 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      1154  0.0  0.7  68812  7376 ?        Ssl  11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/upower
nor       1162  0.0  0.4  45676  4692 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
nor       1163  0.0  0.6  76320  6284 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
nor       1190  0.0  0.4  36576  4256 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
nor       1216  0.0  1.9  94096 18804 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/mate-p
nor       1218  0.0  1.3  50428 12976 ?        Sl   11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/mate-p
nor       1223  0.0  0.4   9532  4072 ?        S    11:12   0:00 /usr/lib/arm-li
nor       1255  0.1  2.3 172240 22532 ?        Sl   11:12   0:02 mate-terminal
nor       1261  0.0  0.1   1936  1100 ?        S    11:12   0:00  \_ gnome-pty-h
nor       1262  0.0  0.4   6424  4168 pts/1    Ss   11:12   0:00  \_ bash
nor       9730  0.0  0.1   4868  1888 pts/1    R+   11:42   0:00      \_ ps faux
root      1492  0.0  0.5  11568  4992 ?        Ss   11:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd
lp        1494  0.0  0.3   8620  3740 ?        S    11:16   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/cu
root      9172  0.0  0.4  25776  4348 ?        Sl   11:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/syste
root      9176  0.1  1.5  17792 15168 ?        S    11:35   0:00 /usr/bin/perl /
root      9561  0.0  0.2   6592  2768 tty2     Ss   11:40   0:00 /bin/login -f  
user      9672  0.5  0.4   6484  3984 tty2     S+   11:40   0:00  \_ -bash
root      9576  0.1  0.2   6592  2768 tty1     Ss   11:40   0:00 /bin/login -f  
user      9673  0.5  0.4   6484  4136 tty1     S+   11:40   0:00  \_ -bash
user      9647  0.0  0.3   5316  3440 ?        Ss   11:40   0:00 /lib/systemd/sy
user      9656  0.0  0.1   8456  1324 ?        S    11:40   0:00  \_ (sd-pam)
```

Вывод команды ls -l /sbin/init

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Հնվ 27 19:59 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, вывод `$ ps faux` и `$ ls -l /sbin/init`. и `$ cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: и `$ grep -r autologin /etc/init* /etc/systemd`

Comment: alt+2|3|4|5|6 и Вы в другой консоле

Comment: @alexanderbarakin выводы добавил в вопрос. Команда grep -r autologin /etc/init* /etc/systemd ничего не выдает.

Comment: @Sergey все консоли автоматически авторизуюутся под пользователем user, и авторизуются даже после команды exit

Comment: попробуйте поискать "/bin/login -f": `$ sudo grep -r '/bin/login -f' /etc /usr/lib/systemd`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin попробовал, тоже ничего не выдает

Comment: ну, попробуйте искать "autologin", "login -f", "login.*-f" и т.д. и т.п. и не в этих двух каталогах, а уж, для надёжности, по всей системе. найдётся много чего, надо будет догадаться, что именно имеет отношение к данному случаю. быстрее будет, конечно, спросить у того, кто это наконфигурировал.